# Django: How to use FilePathField to get file size

Tags: python, django

I work in a postproduction company, we have our media files on a server.  Through the site running on a second server, the user would point to a file, perform some operations (calculating checksums for example) and save the results in the database.

I'm looking for a "best practices" example on how to use FilePathField to get the size of a file.  I've read tutorials and searched in the docs, but I'm having trouble putting the pieces together for my needs.

Some relevant code (**EDIT:** corrected the views, #1 and #3 are printed):

models.py

```
    class AssetTest(models.Model):
        file_path = models.FilePathField(path=r"", default="")
        file_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")
        file_size = models.IntegerField(default=0)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.file_path
```

forms.py

```
class AssetTestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AssetTest
        fields = ("file_name", "file_size")
```

views.py

```
def asset_select(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("1")
        form = AssetTestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("2")
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.file_name = request.FILES['file'].name
            form.file_size = request.FILES['file'].size
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/assetmanage/assets/')

        print("3")

    else:
        print("4")
        form = AssetTestForm()
return render(request, 'assetmanage/asset_select.html', {'form': form})
```

asset_select.html

```
{% extends "assetmanage/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Add Asset{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form class="form-horizontal" name="asset_select" action="/assetmanage/asset/test/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Select a file:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="asset_file">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your FilePathField give the correct path name

```
FilePathField(path="/home/simon/",..)
```

`cleaned_data` of `FilePathField` will give you the exact path so using that to get the file name and file size of it...

```
form = AssetTestForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(commit=False)
    temp_file_obj = TemporaryFileUploadHandler(form.cleaned_data['file_path'])
    form.instance.file_size = temp_file_obj.chunk_size
    form.instance.file_name = form.cleaned_data['file_path'].split("/")[-1]
    form.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my code with your input, see above; #1 and #3 are printed when I hit submit, so the form doesn't seem to validate.

Comment: @SimonTheChain can you print `form.errors` when not valid ?

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>file_size<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>file_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: I looked into your html code.. can you put the `file_name` field ?

Comment: It gives me the same error with just the size field, "field required".

Comment: get rid of `file_size` in your ModelForm. Is not that we are injecting in views?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118600/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-simon-thechain).

Comment: I can't able to guess now. Can I see the code ?